Rails 7 with turbo
I have a rails 7 app and this is my package.json file:
 {
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.2",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.2",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^8.0.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@rails/ujs": "^7.1.3-4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "esbuild": "^0.21.5",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "postcss-cli": "^11.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --format=esm --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets",
    "build:css:compile": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules",
    "build:css:prefix": "postcss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --use=autoprefixer --output=./app/assets/builds/application.css",
    "build:css": "yarn build:css:compile && yarn build:css:prefix",
    "watch:css": "nodemon --watch ./app/assets/stylesheets/ --ext scss --exec \"yarn build:css\""
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"
  ]
}

application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", type: "module" %>

when I click on:
 <%= button_to new_user_registration_path, method: :get, class: 'btn btn-primary' do %>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i> Register today!
      <% end %>

Everything works fine when I click the button mentioned above. However, when I navigate back to the previous page using the browser's back button, the page scrolls from the top to the position I was previously on that page.
I would like to have the normal behavior without the scrolling part. Specifically, I want to click the browser's back button and return to the position I was on that page without the scrolling.
Is this scrolling behavior normal with Turbo? If so, how can I disable it? I find it quite inconvenient.

there is scrolling on turbo frames, but you have to specify that you want to scroll and you want it to be smooth scroll. browser back just takes me straight to the previous scroll position, no animation. why button_to and not just a link_to.

It's a bootstrap issue with turbo. Bootstrap 5 sets the scroll-behavior as smooth. So I added this at the very top of my application.css file $enable-smooth-scroll: false;
